# Integration on a sphere; spherical triangle

Tags: integration

Can you calculate the area of a spherical triangle by integrating the parametric equation of a sphere if you know the coordinates of the vertices and the radius of the sphere with its origin at $(0,0,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can find the angles, then use the [Gauss–Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) in the form for a triangle on a simply-connected surface:
$$ \iint_{\Delta} K \, dS = \alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi $$
In the case of the sphere, the curvature is $1/R^2$, and so the LHS is just $A(\Delta)/R^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering whether I can do something like Integrate[(R**2) Sin(theta), {theta, theta1, theta2}, {phi, phi1, phi2}] where theta1, theta2, phi1, phi2 are determined from the vectors connecting the center of the sphere and the vertices